# On the polynomial ring $ \mathbb{R}[x,y] $, and the sine and cosine functions.

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

I was investigating relationships between commutative algebra and real analysis when the following problem came into mind.

> **Problem.** Let $ P \in \mathbb{R}[x,y] $. If $ P(\sin(\theta),\cos(\theta)) = 0 $ for all $ \theta \in \mathbb{R} $, then is it true that $ P $ lies in the principal ideal $ \langle x^{2} + y^{2} - 1 \rangle $?

This problem does not appear difficult, but I have yet to find a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $ A \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} \mathbb{R}[y] $, so that $ P \in A[x] $. As $ P $ is a **monic** polynomial, there exist polynomials $ Q,R \in A[x] $ such that
$$
P = (x^{2} + y^{2} - 1) Q + R,
$$
where the $ x $-degree of $ R $ is less than $ 2 $. We can thus write
$$
R(x,y) = f(y) x + g(y).
$$

Now, suppose that $ f(y) $ and $ g(y) $ are not zero. Then as
\begin{align}
\forall \theta \in \mathbb{R}: \quad
    0
& = P(\sin(\theta),\cos(\theta)) \\
& = R(\sin(\theta),\cos(\theta)) \\
& = f(\cos(\theta)) \cdot \sin(\theta) + g(\cos(\theta)),
\end{align}
we can deduce that
$$
\forall t \in [0,1]: \quad
f(t) \sqrt{1 - t^{2}} + g(t) = 0,
$$
which implies that $ [f(t)]^{2} (1 - t^{2}) \equiv [g(t)]^{2} $ as polynomials. This is seen to be a contradiction, just by looking at the order of vanishing of both polynomials at $ t = 1 $. Therefore, $ P \in \langle x^{2} + y^{2} - 1 \rangle $.